# Kinetic JS: Zoom an image and keep self build arrow (lines) at same position

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Im trying to zoom an kinetic object(image) in and out (this works).

The problem is i also have an arrow (custom built consits of three lines).

So on the first step i move the arrow to a certain point of the image and when i hit the zoom in action, the image zooms (or sets its scale) corresponing to the zoom factor.

Problem: the tip of the arrow should stay on the same point as it was before the zoom action(on the image) but the arrow object itself shouldnt be zoomed.

Here is the code for my zoom action:

```
    --//ZOOM IN 
    htp.p(q'! document.getElementById('P10005_ZOOM_IN').addEventListener('click',         function() {

    zoom_factor = document.getElementById('P10005_ZOOM_FACTOR').value;
    console.log('zoom factor: ' +zoom_factor);
      var scale = image.getScale();
    console.log('scale: ' +scale);
    console.log('whole ' + parseFloat(image.getScale().x)+parseFloat(zoom_factor));


    //layer get x and y offset
    var x;
    var y;
    var arrow_layer1 = stage.get('.ARROW');

    arrow_layer1.each(function(arr) {

       x = arr.getX();
       y = arr.getY();

    });

    //arrow object
    arrow_layer = stage.get('.arrow');

 if(parseFloat(image.getScale().x)+parseFloat(zoom_factor) < 10)
 {
  console.log('image x before ' + image.getX());

    x_coord = image.getX() + (image.getWidth()*image.getScale().x)/2;
  y_coord = image.getY() + (image.getHeight()*image.getScale().y)/2;

  var old_x = image.getX();
  var old_y = image.getY();
  var oldWidth = image.getWidth();
  var oldHeigth = image.getHeight();

    image.setScale((image.getScale().x)+parseFloat(zoom_factor),(image.getScale().y)+parseFloat(zoom_factor));

    image.setPosition(
        x_coord-image.getWidth()/2*image.getScale().x,
        y_coord-image.getHeight()/2*image.getScale().y);

 var x_pos;
 var y_pos;

 //inserting new arrow positions
    arrow_layer.each(function(arr) {
       console.log(arr);
        console.log(arr.getPoints());

        console.log(arr.getPoints()[3]);    
        console.log(x + ' ' + y);

        var image_x = old_x;
        var image_x_arrow = x;
        var image_x_end = old_x+ oldWidth;

        var image_y = old_y;
        var image_y_arrow = y;
        var image_y_end = old_y+oldHeigth;

        console.log('x settings: ' + image_x + ' ' + image_x_arrow + ' ' + image_x_end);
        console.log('y settings: ' + image_y + ' ' + image_y_arrow + ' ' + image_y_end);

        var  ratio = image_x_arrow-image_x;
        console.log('x ratio: ' + ratio);
        var rat = oldWidth/ratio;
        console.log('x ratio: ' + rat);

        var ratio_y = image_y_arrow-image_y;
        var rat_y = oldHeigth/ratio_y;

        var new_image_x = image.getX();
        console.log('new x position: ' + new_image_x);
        var new_image_x_end = image.getX() + image.getWidth()*image.getScale().x;
        console.log('new image end: ' + new_image_x_end);

        var new_image_y = image.getY();
        var new_image_y_end = image.getY() + image.getHeight()*image.getScale().y;

        var new_x = image.getWidth()*image.getScale().x/rat;
        console.log('x len end: ' + new_x);
        var new_y = image.getHeight()*image.getScale().y/rat_y;

        x_pos = new_image_x+new_x;
      //  x_pos = new_image_x+ ratio*image.getScale().x;
        console.log('new coordoinate: ' + x_pos);
        y_pos = new_image_y+new_y;
       // y_pos = new_image_y+ratio_y*image.getScale().y;

        console.log(x_pos);

    });  


    arrow_layer1.each(function(arr) {    

     arr.setX(x_pos);
     arr.setY(y_pos);


     });


document.getElementById('P10005_ZOOM_CURRENT').value = (image.getScale().x)*100;    
stage.draw();

     }
      }, false); !');
```

Im trying to read the offset from the ARROW layer and store its variables.
Then .arrow will give me the arrow object.

I want to go with the relation of the distances from to "old" image and update it to the ztoomed image, but i think it doesn´t work

any suggestions?

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you can setup your code in a fiddle